# Where does U. come from in this Mysql select table example?

Tags: mysql, select

I saw a tutorial online. but I don't understand the U. mean when it SELECT the table. It also put the U and T behide the table name. Where does the U and T come from? Why the coder put the U and T. Please clarify me, thank you!
the table has no such name. Does the U. mean join? or something else?
I put the example below.

```
CREATE TABLE phpro_tags (
  tag_id INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  tag_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (tag_id),
  UNIQUE KEY tag_name (tag_name)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE phpro_tag_types (
  tag_type_id INT(1) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  tag_type_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (tag_type_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE phpro_tag_targets (
  tag_target_id INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  tag_id INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  tag_target_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  tag_target_url varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  tag_type_id INT(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (tag_target_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES phpro_tags(tag_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (tag_type_id) REFERENCES phpro_tag_types(tag_type_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

.

```
<?php
    $tag_target_url = 'http://phpro.org/tutorials/Managing-Hierarchical-Data-with-PHP-and-MySQL.html';

    try
    {
        include 'db.class.php';

        $sql = "
            SELECT U.*
            FROM phpro_tag_targets U
            JOIN phpro_tag_targets T
            WHERE
                    U.tag_id = T.tag_id
                AND T.tag_target_url = :tag_target_url
            GROUP BY tag_target_url";

        $stmt = db::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':tag_target_url', $tag_target_url);
        $stmt->execute();
        $res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        /*** loop over the array and create the listing ***/
        $msg = '<ul>';
        foreach($res as $val)
        {
            $msg .= '<li><a href="'.$val['tag_target_url'].'">'.$val['tag_target_name'].'</a></li>'."\n";
        }
        $msg .= '</ul>';
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $msg = 'Unable to process tag type';
    }
?>

<?php echo $msg; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The nicer answer is that U and T are aliases defined in the FROM portion of the query.  You can then use them as U.columnname or T.columnname to shorten your typing.  In this case the aliases are needed because they are joining a table to itself.

Answer (score 0):

And as your problem is concerned "U" is the name of the table from which data is retrieved. And "U.*" means to retrieve every column of table "U". It is sometimes uses as U.Id, U.name.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to stack flow. And, I am still confuse. There is no table of U, so why U does exist?

Comment: It is an alias assigned to phpro_tag_targets table